# PHP imap_append with BCC

Tags: php, imap, bcc, php-imap

I'm handling a mailbox for an app, and after sending an e-mail, I'd like to append it in a "Sent" mailbox, and to be able to retrieve recipients (to, cc and bcc).

This works great with the following code...

```
$envelope = imap_mail_compose([
    'subject' => 'test',
    'from' => 'from@test.fr',
    'to' => 'to@test.fr',
    'cc' => 'cc@test.fr',
    'bcc' => 'bcc@test.fr'
], $body);

imap_append($imap, '{ssl0.ovh.net:xxx/ssl}SENT', $envelope);
```

...except for the bcc. If I retrieve the e-mail headers after appending, it seems there is no bcc, whereas there should be! (I can retrieve to and cc addresses).

I can't find why. Did I make a mistake? Did I misunderstand something?

**Edit:** ok, with imap_mail_compose bcc remains invisible (so why can we add a "bcc" parameter, if it is not used?). So, there is no way to append the Bcc addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, trick found.

I create the global message string using imap_mail_compose, like below.

Then, I append the Bcc addresses into that string:

```
// The Bcc string, from an array
$bcc = implode(',', $data['bcc']);

// create the global message string
$envelopeStr = imap_mail_compose($data, $body);

// Appending the Bcc addresses manually
if (!empty($bcc)) {
    // Putting the Bcc just before the main recipients
    // There will be a "To:" parameter for sure, we could have used "Subject:" too
    $pos = strpos($envelopeStr , "To:");
    // Adding the string
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $bccStr = "Bcc: " . $bcc . "\r\n";
        $envelopeStr = substr_replace($envelopeStr , $bccStr, $pos, 0);
    }
}
```